# What Can I Make in a Rice Cooker Besides Rice?

Tags: rice-cooker

I received a rice cooker as a gift. I like to know if anything else I can done with it other than, cook rice. you have some ideas?

Comment: Mine has a timer; one of my favorite things is to put in some old-fashioned slow-cooking steel cut oats and water at night, set the timer, and wake up to hot oatmeal.

Comment: If you google things like "rice cooker recipes" or "things to cook in rice cooker," there's a wealth of other recipes that you can use besides the basic "rice, similar grains, or steamed foods." I've personally made mac and cheese and a frittata, and have a recipe for corn bread I'd like to try out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any grains that cook by absorption, such as bulgur, work well. You can use it for couscous but as that just needs to be soaked in boiling water there not much point.

Wetter foods can be cooked in it but the cutoff won't work, so you'll need to keep an eye on them - only worth it if for some reason you can't put a pan on a stove.

While it is rice-based, risotto is worth a mention: a single pot meal in the rice cooker. It's worth starting from a recipe. Other similar rice-based dishes can also be done.

It's worth getting a rice cooker recipe book if you're feeling adventurous.

Answer (score 3):

Almost anything that can be cooked in a slow cooker (on low) can be done in a rice cooker.

Roger Ebert (the film critic) has a cookbook for rice cookers : [The Pot and How to Use It](https://smile.amazon.com/Pot-How-Use-Mystery-Romance/dp/0740791427)

... but there's lots of other ones out there, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've read that oatmeal works, and probably other types of grains as well. If yours comes with a little steamer insert like mine did, you can steam vegetables in them. There was a fad awhile back of people making cake in them, too.